# Class for user actions

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

I implemented a class for relationships with the user (deletion, name change, check for existence), I created this class to remove extra logic from the activity class. Could you talk about how my code can be improved?

```
class UserActionManager @Inject constructor(private val repository : BaseAppRepository,
                                            private val sharedPreferences : JsonSharedPreferences) {

    fun editUserName(user: User,newUserName: String) {
        Completable.fromAction {
            val userObjective:Objective? = sharedPreferences.loadObject(GlobalConstants.OBJECTIVE_SAVE_KEY + user.userName,Objective::class.java)
            val userProfile:Profile? = sharedPreferences.loadObject(GlobalConstants.PROFILE_SAVE_KEY + user.userName,Profile::class.java)
            sharedPreferences.saveObject<Objective>(GlobalConstants.OBJECTIVE_SAVE_KEY + newUserName, userObjective)
            sharedPreferences.saveObject<Profile>(GlobalConstants.PROFILE_SAVE_KEY + newUserName, userProfile)
            repository.updateUserName(user.userName, newUserName)
            user.userName = newUserName
            repository.updateUser(user)
        }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe()
    }

    fun deleteUser(user: User) {
        Completable.fromAction { repository.deleteUser(user) }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe()
        sharedPreferences.saveObject<Objective>(GlobalConstants.OBJECTIVE_SAVE_KEY + user.userName, null)
        sharedPreferences.saveObject<Profile>(GlobalConstants.PROFILE_SAVE_KEY + user.userName, null)
    }

    fun isEmptyUser(userName: String): Single<Boolean> {
        return repository.getUserByUserName(userName)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .isEmpty
    }
}
```

Comment: Search for kotlin - coroutines. This is the Kotlin-version for RX with a lot of syntactic sugar  maybe https://medium.com/@daptronic/migrate-from-rxjava-to-kotlin-coroutines-a-step-by-step-guide-488d039744cc can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Extract your preferences code into extra class or create extension functions to get those objects. Ex. `sharedPreferences.loadObject(GlobalConstants.OBJECTIVE_SAVE_KEY + user.userName,Objective::class.java)` should have it's own method. Ex. `loadUserByName`.
- You are using kotlin, use it's strengths like non-nullables by default. Does `repository.updateUserName()` really accept nullables? That seems wrong. I'd use it for example with elvis operator `loadUserByName(user.username) ?: error("username not found")`